# How do I add a toolbar with hamburger to each layout?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a menu. When I go to each item, I get to the layout and can't go back, because I don't get a toolbar. What am I doing wrong? This is my first experience with android studio.

I need to be able to open a menu from mycard.xml and go to any layout.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="cards"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="85dp"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/menu_text_style" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_message:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CardActivity.class));
            break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**DataObject.java**:

```
public class DataObject {
    String sender, subject;

    public DataObject(String sender, String subject) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
}
```

**CardActivity.java**:

```
public class CardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mycard);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MailAdapter(getData()));
    }

    private ArrayList<DataObject> getData() {
        ArrayList<DataObject> mailList = new ArrayList<>();
        mailList.add(new DataObject("some text", "ffdddfdf"));
        return mailList;
    }
}
```

**MailAdapter.java**:

```
public class MailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MailAdapter.MailHolder> {

    ArrayList<DataObject> data;
    public MailAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MailHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_file, null, false);
        return new MailHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MailHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvSender.setText(data.get(position).getSender());
        holder.tvSubject.setText(data.get(position).getSubject());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MailHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvSender, tvSubject;
        public MailHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText1);
            tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myText2);

        }
    }
}
```

**mycard.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
I want to see that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thjVP.png)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the Up button for an activity that has a parent activity, call the app bar's setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() method. Typically, you would do this when the activity is created. For example, the following onCreate() method sets a Toolbar as the app bar for MyChildActivity, then enables that app bar's Up button: Sample.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_child)

    // my_child_toolbar is defined in the layout file
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_child_toolbar))

    // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar and enable the Up button
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```

[Java Snippet](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.app.ActionBar/setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled?snippet=5921d2964002b00004d56e07)

Comment: I add this code to CardActivity because I want to see a toolbar there. Right? The very last line in your code is highlighted in red and I don't know how to fix the error. Do I need to create additional methods for this?

Comment: this Kotlin Code. I updated my answer.


Sample : https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.app.ActionBar/setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled?snippet=5921d2964002b00004d56e07

Comment: That didn't work for me( I now have the app crashing.

Comment: Try it : https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-24-how-to-add-back-button-at-toolbar-941e6577418e

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong. I edited the post. I want what's in the picture to appear. Not the back button.

Comment: that's definitely your answer Try it. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer

I thought you wanted to make the back button.